# Matching a space at the beginning of a line using pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a unified diff file using pyparsing as an exercise and I can't get something right. Here the part of my diff file that's causing me troubles :

```
(... some stuff over...)
 banana
+apple
 orange
```

The first line starts with " " then "banana". I have the following expression for parsing a line :

```
linestart = Literal(" ") | Literal("+") | Literal("-")
line = linestart.leaveWhitespace() + restOfLine
```

This works when parsing a single line, but when I try to parse the whole file, the "leaveWhitespace" instruction make the parser start at the end of the last line. In my example, after parsing " banana", the next char is "\n" (because of leaveWhitespace) and the parser tries to match " " or "+" or "-" and so throws an error.

How can I handle this correctly?

Comment: Who gives homework on pyparsing?!

Comment: Me i.e. that's not homework, I just want to learn pyparsing.

Comment: Please visit the wiki at http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com.  There are links to online docs and articles there. And feel free to post questions on the Discussion tab of the wiki home page. Welcome to pyparsing!

Answer (score 1):

You can read and parse one line at a time. The following code works for me.

```
from pyparsing import Literal, restOfLine

linestart = Literal(" ") | Literal("+") | Literal("-")
line = linestart.leaveWhitespace() + restOfLine

f = open("/tmp/test.diff")
for l in f.readlines():
  fields = line.parseString(l)
  print fields
```

And the output is

```
[' ', 'banana']
['+', 'apple']
[' ', 'orange']
```

Or if you have to parse several lines, you can explicitly specify the LineEnd

```
linestart = Literal(" ") | Literal("+") | Literal("-")
line = linestart.leaveWhitespace() + restOfLine + LineEnd()
lines = ZeroOrMore(line)
lines.parseString(f.read())
```

Comment: Yes, that works, but the problem is that I have a bunch of other parser for other parts of the file. I admit that my example was a bit simplified. I'll add some details to the original post.

Comment: You should still be able to parse one line a line even with other things in the file. But I've updated my answer to include a way to parse the whole file as a string. I have to say I'm new to pyparsing and not sure if it's the best practice.